# What's the size of an ASP.NET 3.5 session ID?

Tags: asp.net, security, sessionid

Is it 32 bit, or 64 bit or 128 bit or bigger?

Comment: There are 3 different answers ... which is it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's neither int nor guid; from the [MSDN help file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.sessionidmanager.aspx)...

> The ASP.NET session identifier is a randomly generated number encoded into a 24-character string consisting of lowercase characters from a to z and numbers from 0 to 5.

Comment: ... which makes it 120 bits.

Comment: Answer is not relevant to what is asked here! It was supposed to simply size instead of specifying what's generated with string length... Though it increases someone's knowledge.

Comment: When I saw this question, this is the answer I was looking for:  "Session IDs are a 120-bit random number that is represented by a 20-character string" from [https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/899918](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/899918)

Answer (score 4):

The reason for the extra 8 characters in the database vs what you get in code is the application id.  In the database the session is appended with the tempApplicationID from ASPStateTempApplications table.  This is why you get 24 characters in code, and 32 in the db.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with 88 bytes. If you look at the ASP.NET state database, that is how it is defined.

Answer (score -2):

Because it's generated as a [System.Guid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid(VS.90).aspx) Valuetype, it's a 128-bit integer, which is 16 bytes.

Comment: This is incorrect.  AFAIK, GUIDs were used in ASP Classic but dropped in ASP.Net because the GUID generation was too predictable and that resulted in a security flaw.